# JQuery Mobile Links with MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-mobile

I'm setting up a JQuery mobile site with ASP.NET MVC 3 and the Razor UI.  I'm generating my links like:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("View", "Users", new { Group = 2 })' data-role="button">See Group 2</a>
```

Say I'm accessing it from Home/Index.  The issue I'm having is when I click on the link, it does:

http://localhost/myapp/Home/Index#myapp/Users/View

I also tried the direct helper `@Html.ActionLink("View", "Users", ...)` and I'm getting the same issue with the URL's, and it's causing the application to break.  Putting a / before the link is worse.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: have you specified some custom routes... if yes how does they look like

Comment: @3nigma No custom rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Per link you can do this:**

Set a `rel=external` attribute, or set any `target` attribute.

**Globally you can do this:**

```
$(window.document).bind("mobileinit", function() {

    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;

});
```

[jQuery Mobile's navigation model](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html)

Comment: Has this worked for anyone, I still get the # tags which break validation etc? url = http://localhost/#/Account/Login