# jquery.mobile, asp.net, native anchor handling

Tags: asp.net, ipad, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8

I have an application that I am developing with jquery.mobile (1.3.1) over asp.net 4.5.

The first page consists of a list, the selection of an item in that list leads to another page. I have developed the pages separately.

When I click one of the items in the list, the second page is shown correctly but the URL is incorrect. I believe this is because jquery.mobile is intercepting the link click and handling the page transition itself - I do not want this and would prefer the link to behave naturally.

- The URL to the page in question: `http://myhost/mobile`
- The URL I am linking to: `http://myhost/mobile/NewClient.aspx`
- The URL shown: `http://myhost/mobile/#/myhost/mobile/NewClient.aspx?ClientID...`

The page list code:

```
  <div data-role="page" id="logon" data-theme="c">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h1>Select location</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <asp:ListView ID="LocationList" runat="server"
        ItemType="AGP.BackOffice.Model.ClientSource"
        DataKeyNames="ID" SelectMethod="LocationList_SelectMethod"
        OnItemDataBound="LocationList_ItemDataBound">
        <LayoutTemplate>
          <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-divider-theme="b">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
          </ul>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <li data-theme="c">
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Mobile/NewClient.aspx?ClientSourceID={0}&IsMinimalDataCapture={1}"
                            data-transition="slide" Text="<%#: Item.Description %>" />
          </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:ListView>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have found various articles claiming that the built in page handling in jquery.mobile can be turned off as follows...

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
      $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
      $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
    });
  </script>
```

I have added this before the data-role="page" div, however it makes no difference.

Can anybody shed any light on this? I just want the links to be handled as they are by the browser whilst still taking advantage of the jquery.mobile UI elements.

I should also point out that this behaviour is only seen on mobile devices (tested on WP8 & iPad). On the desktop, the URL seems to be fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this: [JQuery Mobile Links with MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247370/jquery-mobile-links-with-mvc)

Removed my JavaScript and added `rel="external"` to each of the anchor tags. They now operate as desired.

Would still be interested to know though if there is a better way to address this.

Comment: Seems you can also specify data-ajax="false" as an attribute on any element and that will prevent any contained element from being intercepted by the JQM ajax.